# Change IP Of Process Using Proxy

Tags: c#, proxy

I want to change the ip address of each application using a proxy but my code is not giving the results I want.

I tried by opening chrome from the script but its ip address still cannot be changed.

Here is my code:

```
LaunchProcessWithProxy("process.exe", "proxy.example.com", 1080, "username", "password");

public void LaunchProcessWithProxy(string processPath, string proxyHost, int proxyPort, string proxyUsername, string proxyPassword)
{
         ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
         startInfo.FileName = processPath;
         startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
         startInfo.EnvironmentVariables["ALL_PROXY"] = $"socks5://{proxyHost}:{proxyPort}@{proxyUsername}:{proxyPassword}";

         using (Process process = Process.Start(startInfo))
         {
             process.WaitForExit();
         }
     }
```

Comment: Using a proxy and "changing the IP address" are two different things (not sure how the latter even makes sense). `ALL_PROXY` is a Unix environment variable, I don't think it works in Windows.